# how to set href attribute in javascript with value to call route

Tags: laravel

i am trying to set url in jquery ajax, as

```
$.ajax({
      url : "{{url('addtocart')}}",
      type : "POST",
      data : {_token: CSRF_TOKEN, username:username, userType:userType,
            table_no:table_no, order_no:order_no, cname:cname,
            tname:tname, dname:dname, dish_qty:dish_qty,
            chefnote:chefnote
              },
      success : function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        $('#cartOrder').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              drawRow(data[i]);
            }
        function drawRow(rowData) {
                var row = $("<tr />")
                row.empty();
                $("#cartOrder").append(row);
                row.append($("<td contenteditable='true'>" + rowData.dish + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td contenteditable='true'>" + rowData.dish_qty + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td contenteditable='true'>" + rowData.chefnote + "</td>"));
                row.append($("<td>" +"<a href='"<?php echo 'Edit';?>"' value='"+rowData.ord_id+"'>" +"Edit | "+"</a>" +"<a href='' value='"+rowData.ord_id+"'>" +"Delete"+"</a>" + "</td>"));
            }
      }
```

as there u can see at last line href="Edit", i want to call route on click of that link with value as

```
<a href="<?php echo 'Editcat/'.RowData->ord_id; ?>"
```

i know this not the way, how can i do that ?? thank you.

Comment: can you show your code for how you have defined the Route for Edit..

Comment: it can be like this Route::get('Edit/{id}','Controller@function');

Answer (score 0):

There are many options of achieving this:

First:

You can keep the call url in any of the tag's data attributes, suppose this is your container related to the ajax functionality:

```
<div class="_cart" data-edit-url="{{route('cart.edit',['id'=>$cartItem->id])}}">

</div>
```

and access it using the following code:

```
$('._cart').data('edit-url');
```

but before executing this line `http://stackoverflow.com/users/6285124/rohit-khatri`

Define a name for your route, like:

```
Route::get('Edit/{id}','Controller@function')->name('cart.edit');
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your route you just have to change it like this -

**Route**

```
Route::get('/Edit/{id}',[
        'uses' => 'Controller@function',
        'as' => 'Edit',
    ]);
```

and than you can use it in your view like this -

```
<a href="{{ route('Edit', ['id' => "your Id here"]) }}">Edit</a>
//this is your route ^      here will be your Id ^
```

than in your **Controller** for edit you can use this Id -

```
public function yourEditFunction($id){
        //use $id here
        }
```

Comment: but how can i call this in jquery as u can see above , i am trying to call through jquery,

Comment: well where you are appending the edit link in jquery just place the code that I mentioned for the view..